# Recording/Catching push notifications with chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, push-notification, notifications, record

I'm trying to catch push notifications that get sent to my chrome browser with a chrome extension to then write it to a file or run code on receiving it.
I'm sure the issue I'm having is simple enough for some of you so I will share what I've found so far and my code.

notifhook.js

```
(function() {
    // save the original function
    var origCreateNotif = notifications.createNotification;

    // overwrite createNotification with a new function
    notifications.createNotification = function(img, title, body) {

        // call the original notification function
        var result = origCreateNotif.apply(this, arguments);

        alert("Function was called");

        // bind a listener for when the notification is displayed
        result.addEventListener("display", function() {
            alert("Triggered code");
            // do something when the notification is displayed
        });

        return result;
    }
})()
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Push",
  "description": "Relay push notifications",
  "version": "3.0",
  "permissions": ["notifications"],
  "web_accessible_resources": ["notifhook.js"],
  "content_scripts" : [{
    "run_at" : "document_start",
    "matches" : ["<all_urls>"],
    "js" : ["inject.js"]
  }],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

inject.js

```
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL("notifhook.js");
document.documentElement.appendChild(s);
```

Most of the code used was taken here :
[How can I listen to notifications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949606/how-can-i-listen-to-notifications)

I am using this webapp to test my extension :
http://ttsvetko.github.io/HTML5-Desktop-Notifications/

So, to my knowledge what is happening so far is that the  block containing my main function is being added to the webpage just fine
since I can alert at the start of it and on every page load it will be triggered.

What is failing is when I receive a push notification the event listener isn't working or my function names are wrong. I read somewhere that webkitNotifications was replaced with just 'notifications'.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: does push notification fire when the web app is closed? if so the push notificaton will be in servis worker and your script will not fire, you will need to overwrite registration of service worker with your script and call importScripts with original.

Comment: as long as chrome is open I get the notification yes. 
How would you go about overwriting the registration though ?

Comment: by open I mean the page not the browser, if you get notifications while you close browser tab (like on facebook) then it mean that the notifications came from service worker.

Answer (score 0):

If the code is in service worker, like when there are notifications when you close the browser tab/window for the app (like on facebook) then you need to overwirte registration of service worker.

```
// taken from https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/service-worker/post-message/index.html
function sendMessage(message) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var messageChannel = new MessageChannel();
    messageChannel.port1.onmessage = function(event) {
      if (event.data.error) {
        reject(event.data.error);
      } else {
        resolve(event.data);
      }
    };
    navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage(message,
      [messageChannel.port2]);
  });
}

(function() {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    var register = navigator.serviceWorker.register;
    navigator.serviceWorker.register = function() {
      register.call(navigator.serviceWorker, "yourscript.js").then(function() {
        sendMessage({args: [].slice.call(arguments)});
      });
    };
  }
})();
```

and in service worker (yourscript.js) you need to call importScript with original script taken from post message

```
// put content of notifhook.js file here
self.addEventListener('message', function handler(event) {
  if (event.data && event.data.args && event.data.args.length) {
    importScripts(event.data.args[0]); // import original script
    self.removeEventListener('message', handler);
  }
});
```