# Chrome extension JS event for browser notification + method to modify

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, notifications

I'm writing a chrome extension which will perform some actions when a system notification pops up. Specifically, I want to close them.

For example: the "Restore pages?" notification:
[image: restore_pages_picture]

My manifest file has nothing particularly interesting, here is my event page:

```
function anyAlarmHandler (Alarm anyAlarm) {
  // For now, just clear any alarm when one pops up.
  chrome.alarms.clear(anyAlarm);
}

chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(anyAlarmHandler);
```

But it doesn't clear the system notification as expected.

I suspect that I'm listening for the wrong event, that system notifications are not actually considered an alarm. But the 'notifications' API doesn't have anything regarding catching notifications.

I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949606/how-can-i-listen-to-notifications) regarding catching notifications, which might work, but it doesn't help with the following:

- I need to catch notifications created by the browser itself, not another extension (this might not matter, I'm not sure)
- I need to modify that notification. Change the text, close it, whatever.

I've tried using the code in the link above and just popping some dialogue box when a notification happens (to test if that solution works for detecting browser notifications), but even that didn't work. I'm hoping that I'm just missing some method/event listener in some API, but I can't seem to find it anywhere. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "Restore pages?" is not a notification, nor an alarm, and AFAIK the only way to detect it is to check if only new tab page is open on browser startup and then check if many tabs were opened in a small time window.

Comment: @wOxxOm Well that's disheartening. So, say I did that... do you know of a way to then control that box? For instance, to close it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot detect, or override, any of the Chrome's own UI popups like this.

Only another native app could potentially interact with them (e.g. simulate a click).

Short of patching Chrome (in-memory or on disk), you won't be able to change the wording.